# Python AppEngine MapReduce

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-app-engine-python

i have created a pretty simple MapReduce pipeline, but i am having a cryptic:

`PipelineSetupError: Error starting production.cron.pipelines.ItemsInfoPipeline(*(), **{})#a741186284ed4fb8a4cd06e38921beff:`

when i try to start it. This is the pipeline code:

```
class ItemsInfoPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
"""
"""

    def run(self):
        output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
            job_name="items_job",
            mapper_spec="production.cron.mappers.items_info_mapper",
            input_reader_spec="mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
            mapper_params={
                "input_reader": {
                    "entity_kind": "production.models.Transaction"
                }
            }
        )

        yield ItemsInfoStorePipeline(output)


class ItemsInfoStorePipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
"""
"""

    def run(self, statistics):
        print statistics
        return "OK"
```

Of course i have double checked that the mapper path is right, and take into account that ItemsInfoStorePipeline is not doing anything because i am focusing the have the pipeline started, which is not happening.

It is all triggered by a Flask view, the following:

```
class ItemsInfoMRJob(views.MethodView):
"""

It's based on transacions.

"""

    def get(self):
    """

    :return:
    """
        pipeline = ItemsInfoPipeline()
        pipeline.start()

        redirect_url = "%s/status?root=%s" % (pipeline.base_path, pipeline.pipeline_id)

        return flask.redirect(redirect_url)
```

I am using `GoogleAppEngineMapReduce==1.9.22.0`

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

The above code works once deployed.

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently there's more people dealing with this:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this. I have a code base that's using pipelines and works fine in OSX. I had another developer using OSX that simply nothing I do seems to get it working, he gets this:

> Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: PipelineSetupError

I've tried swapping versions around and making our PC's match perfectly and it continue to happen. I finally broke down and built an Ubuntu image in docker. I'm also doing my best to match our versions of AppEngine and libraries perfectly.

It also refuses to start with the same message. I started working through the libraries uncommenting the part that's swallowing the error but that was a long rabbit hole I started down because lots of stuff above it also seems to be swallowing up whatever is going on.

Comment: Interesting. Can you paste here the result of the following:

`which dev_appserver.py` ?

Would be really useful.

Comment: It only worked on that one machine. My osx box is working fine. Out of desperation I created a docker image base on Ubuntu, and that is reliably throwing this error and the above does not fix it.